# SharePoint Jquery Condition

Tags: development

I am very new to SharePoint development and code. I do have a requirement to have a conditional Jquery in SharePoint list form. In a list there are 5 columns/fields and all are text type. If a user left the 2nd column then third column will be hide but will be able to enter data in 4th and 5th column. Kindly help me to have an exact code for this requirement.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have to use jQuery? InfoPath can accomplish this easily.  Though, InfoPath has been deprecated, so maybe not a good idea.

Comment: What have you tried? Please make an attempt before posting on this site. We are not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function from this [post](http://sympmarc.com/2012/11/29/easily-hide-columns-on-a-sharepoint-form-with-jquery/):

```
 // Function to hide a column's row in the form
    function hideColumn(c) {
      $(".ms-formlabel h3 nobr").filter(function() {
        var thisText = $.trim($(this).clone().children().remove().end().text());
     //   alert("::" + thisText + "::");
        return thisText.indexOf(c) === 0 && thisText.length === c.length;
      }).closest("tr").hide();
    }
```

All you need to pass it is the DisplayName of the column.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  hideColumn("Your column name");
});
```

And use .on() jquery function with 'focusout' event for your 2nd column

Comment: Just a note to you and @Aveenav here is an [alternative to fetching fields with jQuery](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11153698) that you might find interesting. It is clean and should actually be relatively fast, and best of all it works on internal names instead of title/display name. Works in 2010 and 2013 and default forms (will not work on custom forms)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet to toggle show/hide the next TR element. You may have to modify it according to your needs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 //DOM Ready
 toggleNextElement();
});  

//Bind Key up
$('input[title^="Title"]:eq(0)').keyup(function(e) {
  toggleNextElement();
})

function toggleNextElement() {
 var columnOne = $('input[title^="Title"]:eq(0)'); //Change Title to your column name
 if(columnOne.val().length === 0) {
   columnOne.closest('tr').next('tr').hide();
 }
 else {
   columnOne.closest('tr').next('tr').show();
 }
}
```